# Cannot connect ganache-cli to metamask

Tags: solidity, metamask, ganache

I am trying to follow the truffle pet shop tutorial. But failed to connect metamask with ganache-cli
I ran ganache-cli in the console and changed the rpc url to http://127.0.0.1:8545
But the addresses are still not loading and neither the balance is going up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to connect metamask to ganache-cli you need:

1. run ganache-cli (if you run it with parameters, pls provide them, would be better provide execution command)
2. choose "Localhost 8545" in list of Networks in metamask

Comment: I tried its not working

Comment: have you connected metamask to "Localhost 8545" or you see loader in metamask?

Comment: If metamask connected successfully, but you can’t see accounts, it is normal, you need to import accounts from ganache-cli manually.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You need to copy private key in ganache-cli, then open metamask -> click on account -> click on "Import Account" -> put private key into field -> click Import -> switch account (if needed). Imported account should have 100Eth. Do not forget to select network "Localhost 8545"

Answer (score 0):

What i did is
go to custom rpc 
and paste ganache url i.e http://127.0.0.1:7545 to new rpc url and then save it....  worked for me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a miner issue I guess.
Check the **Port** of GANACHE running in your PC. METAMASK connects with the port number **8545**. And if your GANACHE is not running in that PORT, you'll face the issue. (sometimes
ganache runs on **7545** instead of **8545**)
This issue can be solved either changing the port number in the server configuration of your GANACHE setup.
OR through changing the network from localhost at **8545** to **custom rpc** and by adding  **http://127.0.0.1:7545** as URL.